why is z spread and asw spread similar when cash price is around par?
I break down my questions to below two sub questions

based on my understanding, asw spread is the spread added to the floating leg in the interest rate swap so that the present value of the floating leg is the same as the fixed leg (the bond cashflows). in this interest rate swap, are cashflows discounted using swap zero curve?
based on my understand, z spread is the spread added to the swap zero curve which forms the new discounting curve to discount bond cashflows. how do I understand that the results from these two sets of calculations (being z spread and asw spread respectively) are usually similar only when cash price is around par? is there an intuitive way to understand why are they similar in the first place?

many thanks!

Method 1 is equivalent to changing the cashflows on the bond until you hit the right price.  Method 2 is equivalent to changing the discount rate until you hit the right price.  These will be similar if the bond sensitivity to a change in coupon equals its sensitivity to a change in yield.  Turns out they are equal (to first order) for bonds at par.
You can do the full bond math proof.  My intuition for it is as follows: let $P(c,y)$ be the price of a bond with coupon $c$ and yield $y$.  Since the bond is at par, $y=c$ initially. For example $P(5.00,5.00)=100$.  Now I claim that $P(5.01,5.00)=P(5.00,4.99)$ because changing the coupon is the same as reducing the discount rate: $$P(5.01,5.00)
=A(0.01,5.00) + P(5.00,5.00)= A(0.01,5.00) + P(4.99,4.99)= P(5.00,4.99)$$ as required,where  A is the PV of an annuity. The first step is from additivity of cash flows, and the last step is correct to first order  because the value of the annuity is slightly different in the two discount rates.
